# Print failure from 12.04 to XP

Tags: printing

After upgrading to 12.04 I lost the ability to SAMBA print VIA an XP machine.

Did fresh 12.04 install then added a new printer.
Loaded the correct drivers (Canon PIXMA4200)

Tried a test page.
Printer seems to respond normally but doesn't print anything then locks up.
Have to power cycle printer to unfreeze it.

Tried two different printers on two different XP boxes. Both freeze.

Any possible solution?

Thanks

Comment: After unsuccessfully trying various configurations, including using a router with a printer port, I tried a driver for the PIXMA-IP4000 and it works. Looks like the IP4200 driver is broken.

Comment: Added as community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

Per the OP's comment:

> After unsuccessfully trying various configurations, including using a
>   router with a printer port, I tried a driver for the PIXMA-IP4000 and
>   it works. Looks like the IP4200 driver is broken.